# How to use a csv file for multiple file inputs in command line argument of Bash Script?

Tags: bash, shell, csv, arguments

Hi I am using this script named analysis.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

SAMPLENAME=$1;
SAVEDATA=$2;
DATAPATH=$3;
REFERENCE=$4

......
```

I want to give input of multiple files in CSV format instead of putting individual files details every time as to multiple files can be parsed through single script.

e.g. i have two files ABC and XYZ

so in order to analyse these two files i give these commands

## For ABC

```
analysis.sh ABC /home/myfolder1  /home/datafolder1 /home/referncefolder1
```

## and for XYZ

```
analysis.sh XYZ /home/myfolder2  /home/datafolder2 /home/referncefolder2
```

if i have 100 different files, how to use a single CSV file with details of these 100 files in it that can be parsed through the command line arguments of this bash script?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the name of the csv file as a single argument and have your script read it line by line:

```
csv=$1
while IFS=, read -r filename savedata datapath reference; do
  # do the processing
done < "$csv"
```

---

See this post to understand more about how to read a text file in Bash:

- [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646525/6862601)

You may want to read more about the shell variable naming convention:

- [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)